Does the Universal Enveloping Algebra functor induce an adjunction?
I'm new to lie theory, which I'm interested in as a possible example of a phenomenon that I'm studying in the context of general algebra. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me an answer to the following questions (and possibly some related references), before embracing a study that could be wrong-directed in principle.
Given a field $K$ and a $K$-algebra, it is easy to get a Lie algebra over $K$ by defining the bracket as the commutator $[X,Y]=XY-YX$. Let $R:K-\mathrm{alg}\rightarrow \mathrm{LieAlg}_K$ the corresponding functor.
To every Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ we can associate canonically a universal enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ and to this the associated graded $\mathrm{gr}\,\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.
1-Does this assignment $\mathfrak{g}\mapsto\mathrm{gr}\,\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ give a well-defined functor $L:\mathrm{LieAlg}_K\rightarrow  K\mathrm{-alg}$? (it seems this is the case, but as I mentioned before, I'm new to the topic and I didn't find any evidence in the literature).
2-If this is the case, is this functor $L$ a left-adjoint of the functor $R$ above?
I'm asking this since I'm trying to understand if there is a functor from $\mathrm{LieAlg}_K$ to $K\mathrm{-alg}$ preserving coproducts and mapping free objects in free objects of the same rank.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the graded algebra" - if you mean taking the associated graded, this is not functorial. It is true that $\mathfrak{g} \mapsto U(\mathfrak{g})$ is functorial and is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor from algebras to Lie algebras; this is more or less a matter of chasing through the definition of the universal enveloping algebra to verify the adjunction in the form
$$\text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}}(U(\mathfrak{g}), A) \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Lie}}(\mathfrak{g}, A).$$
Basically the point is that the universal enveloping algebra is exactly defined in such a way to make this true.

I'm asking this since I'm trying to understand if there is a functor from $\mathrm{LieAlg}_K$ to $K\mathrm{-alg}$ preserving coproducts and mapping free objects in free objects of the same rank.

Since left adjoints preserve colimits, this also follows. Namely, $U(-)$ maps free products of Lie algebras to free products of algebras, and in particular maps the free Lie algebra on $n$ generators (where $n$ may be infinite) to the free algebra on $n$ generators. Said a little more invariantly, if $V$ is a vector space we have a natural isomorphism
$$T(V) \cong U(L(V))$$
between the tensor algebra of $V$ and the universal enveloping algebra of the free Lie algebra on $V$. Together with the known computation of the associated graded of $U$, this can be used, among other things, to determine the dimensions of the graded pieces of the free Lie algebra on $n$ generators. You can see a more general version of this calculation done here in the super case.

That was exactly what I meant. Thank you very much!
Do you know if the functor $U(-)$ is surjective-on-objects?

@F. Salviati: I assume you mean up to isomorphism. No, not even close. Universal enveloping algebras have many special properties, most basically they have a counit $U(\mathfrak{g}) \to K$, but also they are Hopf algebras, they are integral domains, etc. Also the only commutative ones are polynomial algebras (since they are commutative iff $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian).

@F. Salviati: that is true and is what I discuss in the second half of my answer.

Yeah, you're right: it actually follows straightforwardly from what you said. Sorry.
